# Not able to start Thread from Laravel Command

Tags: php, multithreading, laravel-5, pthreads

I am new to pthreads in php. I have learnt that it is not possible to start it from apache through a webserver so I have resorted into using laravel commands to run it from the command line but I get this error when I call the 
start() 
method of the thread

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed in [no active file]:0

Stack trace:

#0 {main}

thrown in [no active file] on line 0
```

but the error goes away whenever I call the run method, which is not the way to go.

I will really appreciate any help I can get.

the handle method of my command goes thus

```
public function handle()
{
    $threads = ["Thread One", "Thread Two"];
    $threadList=[];
    foreach ($threads as &$thread){
        //$id++;
        $this->info($thread);
        $testThread = new TestThread($thread);
        $testThread->start();
        $threadList[] = $testThread;
    }

    foreach ($threadList as $thread){
        $this->info("waiting for thread ". $thread->getThreadID());
        $thread->join();
        $this->info($thread->getThreadID()."done ");
        //echo $thread->getThreadID().'<br/>';
    }
}
```

and my ThreadClass is this

```
namespace App\Engine\Threads\ThreadClass;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class TestThread extends \Thread
{
    private $threadID;

    public function __construct($threadID)
    {
        $this->threadID = $threadID;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
    */
    public function getThreadID()
    {
       return $this->threadID;
    }

    public function run()
    {
       $this->threadID = $this->threadID.''.mt_rand(4000, 5000);

    }


 }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55160037/4384751

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem by adding the following argument to the start function

```
$testThread->start(PTHREADS_INHERIT_ALL ^ PTHREADS_INHERIT_CLASSES);
```

courtesy of this question  [Fatal error while starting threads within symfony command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38615825/fatal-error-while-starting-threads-within-symfony-command?rq=1)

Comment: This had me stumped for a couple of days, thank you.